# It does not work to modify css value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I want to achieve the effect that when I click the button of 'Design Custom Cables & Order Online', the accordion content of step 1 will collapse and step 2 content will expand immediately, however, after applying the jquery, the step2 content won't expand immediately and the step 1 content won't collapse as well, can anyone master help me out, appreciate it!

```js
$( document ).ready(function()
{
    /*--hide step2 content but show step1's--*/
    $('#F-step1-cont').css('display', 'block');
    $('#F-step2-cont').css('display', 'none');
   

    /*--disable step2 title button initially--*/
    $('#F-step2-title-btn').attr("disabled", true);


    /*----------accordion effect part------------*/
    $('.F-accordion-container-div').click(function ()
    {
        let id = $(this).find('.F-accordion-content').attr('id');
        switch (id)
        {
            case 'F-step1-cont':
                $('#F-step1-cont').css('display', 'block');
                $('#F-step2-cont').css('display', 'none');
                break;
            case 'F-step2-cont':
                $('#F-step1-cont').css('display', 'none');
                $('#F-step2-cont').css('display', 'block');
                break;
      
        }
    });

    $('#F-step1-content-left').click(function ()
    {
        $('#F-step2-cont').css('display', 'block');
        $('#F-step1-cont').css('display', 'none');
  $('#F-step2-title-btn').attr("disabled", false);
    });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS.css">
    <!--Jquery-->
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
    

<body>
    <!----Step 1---->
        <div class="F-accordion-container-div">
        <div class="F-accordion-caption">
            <button class="F-accordion-caption-btn">&nbsp;&nbsp;Step 1: &nbsp;Select Cable Builder Tool</button>
        </div>
        <div class="F-accordion-content" id="F-step1-cont">
            <div class="F-step1-content" id="F-step1-content-left">
                <button class="F-step1-content-btn" >Design Custom Cables & Order Online</button>
                <ul>
                  <li>Design using common parts</li>
                  <li>Receive instant pricing</li>
                  <li>Order through shopping cart</li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--
            --><div class="F-step1-content"> 
                <button class="F-step1-content-btn">Send Us Specifications</button>
                <ul>
                  <li>Easy-to-use form</li>
                  <li>Personalized service from our staff</li>
                  <li>Request proceeded quickly</li>
                </ul>
            </div>    
        </div>
        </div>
        
        <!----Step 2---->
        <div class="F-accordion-container-div">
        <div class="F-accordion-caption" >
            <button class="F-accordion-caption-btn" id="F-step2-title-btn">&nbsp;&nbsp;Step 2: &nbsp;Select Type</button>
        </div>
        <div class="F-accordion-content" id="F-step2-cont">
            <div class="F-step2-tile-div">
                <img class="F-step2-img" src="imgs/types/bundle.PNG"><!--
                --><div class="F-step2-und-img-ribn">Fiber Optic Assemblies</div>
            </div>
            <div class="F-step2-tile-div">
                <img class="F-step2-img" src="imgs/types/single.png">
                <div class="F-step2-und-img-ribn">Fiber Optic Jumper</div>
            </div>
            <div class="F-step2-tile-div">
                <img class="F-step2-img" src="imgs/types/bundle.PNG">
                <div class="F-step2-und-img-ribn">Copper Cable Assemblies</div>
            </div>
            <div class="F-step2-tile-div">
                <img class="F-step2-img" src="imgs/types/single.png">
                <div class="F-step2-und-img-ribn">Copper Patch Cable</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    
</body>

    
<foot>
    <script src="js.js" ></script>
</foot>
</html>
```

Comment: $('#F-step1-content-left').click(function ()
    {
        $('#F-step2-cont').css('display', 'block');
        $('#F-step1-cont').css('display', 'none');
  $('#F-step2-title-btn').attr("disabled", false);
    });

Comment: the code shown above does not work.

Answer (score 0):

*it should work in normal **but** its inside a parent with a click handler .. so to avoid this use*

> [**e.stopPropagation()**](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) Prevents the event
>   from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from
>   being notified of the event.

```js
$( document ).ready(function()
{
    /*--hide step2 content but show step1's--*/
    $('#F-step1-cont').css('display', 'block');
    $('#F-step2-cont').css('display', 'none');
   

    /*--disable step2 title button initially--*/
    $('#F-step2-title-btn').attr("disabled", true);


    /*----------accordion effect part------------*/
    $('.F-accordion-container-div').click(function ()
    {
        let id = $(this).find('.F-accordion-content').attr('id');
        switch (id)
        {
            case 'F-step1-cont':
                $('#F-step1-cont').css('display', 'block');
                $('#F-step2-cont').css('display', 'none');
                break;
            case 'F-step2-cont':
                $('#F-step1-cont').css('display', 'none');
                $('#F-step2-cont').css('display', 'block');
                break;
      
        }
    });

    $('#F-step1-content-left button').click(function (e)
    {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('#F-step2-cont').css('display', 'block');
        $('#F-step1-cont').css('display', 'none');
      $('#F-step2-title-btn').attr("disabled", false);
    });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS.css">
    <!--Jquery-->
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
    


    <!----Step 1---->
        <div class="F-accordion-container-div">
        <div class="F-accordion-caption">
            <button class="F-accordion-caption-btn">&nbsp;&nbsp;Step 1: &nbsp;Select Cable Builder Tool</button>
        </div>
        <div class="F-accordion-content" id="F-step1-cont">
            <div class="F-step1-content" id="F-step1-content-left">
                <button class="F-step1-content-btn" >Design Custom Cables & Order Online</button>
                <ul>
                  <li>Design using common parts</li>
                  <li>Receive instant pricing</li>
                  <li>Order through shopping cart</li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--
            --><div class="F-step1-content"> 
                <button class="F-step1-content-btn">Send Us Specifications</button>
                <ul>
                  <li>Easy-to-use form</li>
                  <li>Personalized service from our staff</li>
                  <li>Request proceeded quickly</li>
                </ul>
            </div>    
        </div>
        </div>
        
        <!----Step 2---->
        <div class="F-accordion-container-div">
        <div class="F-accordion-caption" >
            <button class="F-accordion-caption-btn" id="F-step2-title-btn">&nbsp;&nbsp;Step 2: &nbsp;Select Type</button>
        </div>
        <div class="F-accordion-content" id="F-step2-cont">
            <div class="F-step2-tile-div">
                <img class="F-step2-img" src="imgs/types/bundle.PNG"><!--
                --><div class="F-step2-und-img-ribn">Fiber Optic Assemblies</div>
            </div>
            <div class="F-step2-tile-div">
                <img class="F-step2-img" src="imgs/types/single.png">
                <div class="F-step2-und-img-ribn">Fiber Optic Jumper</div>
            </div>
            <div class="F-step2-tile-div">
                <img class="F-step2-img" src="imgs/types/bundle.PNG">
                <div class="F-step2-und-img-ribn">Copper Cable Assemblies</div>
            </div>
            <div class="F-step2-tile-div">
                <img class="F-step2-img" src="imgs/types/single.png">
                <div class="F-step2-und-img-ribn">Copper Patch Cable</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: This approach really reaches the effect I want. Thank you so much and appreciate it!

Comment: You'r totally welcome @HanqingZhao .. and please don't forget to accept the answer .. Have a great day :-)